# Como realizar um push notification antes de um determinado prazo em ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, google-cloud-messaging

Olá , vou tentar esclarecer o máximo da minha dúvida , vamos por partes:

Meu usuário irá agendar uma tarefa com data e hora marcada, por exemplo, marcou uma tarefa no dia 20 de outubro de 2017 às 15:00 horas e outros usuários irão ver essa tarefa marcada , essas informações irão para um backend.

Como poderia enviar uma push notification no dia 20 de outubro de 2017 às 14:00 (1 hora antes) avisando a confirmação dessa tarefa?

Comment: Nunca usei Ionic más creio que o backend onde a aplicação esta subscrita deva enviar a notificação push ou (caso a subscrição não esteja neste backend) este backend deva enviar para um serviço aonde a aplicação esta subscrita